# Conditional HTML attribute

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In ActionView I need to display an attribute based on a condition.

```
<%= f.text_field :regmax_remote, {
  :class => 'span2', 
  :style => "display:#{@event.regmax_remote.present? ? "block" : "none"};"
} 
%>
```

Is there a prettier way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code is fine, If you are going to use it only once in the,

But If this will be used in many places then u may need helper

```
def event_display_style event
  event.regmax_remote.present? ? "block" : "none"
end
```

if you have multiple attributes based on several conditions then u can use the helper to return the attributes in hash format and use it like this.

```
<%= f.text_field :regmax_remote, event_display_style(@event) %>
```

if u want a variable hash with default hash then u can do something like this as well

```
<%= f.text_field :regmax_remote, {class: "span2"}.merge(event_display_style(@event)) %>
```

There are some other ways to make this code look better. U may also like the draper gem. which gives an object oriented control over displaying at the same time can acce view helpers.

https://github.com/drapergem/draper

Answer (score 0):

You can try like the following,

```
<% if (@event.regmax_remote.present?) %>
  <%= f.text_field :regmax_remote, class: "span2" %>
<% end %>
```

Do not copy the same, just edit as per your code and use this as the example.

Comment: This will not work, because the element needs to be added to the form, since I will toggle it later with javascript

Comment: You need to describe your question clearly. Which field you gonna need to display and on what condition